# TextBox Value Disappears after closing and reopening form

Tags: vb6

I have two forms: Form 1 and Form 2.

Form 1 has two Buttons and Form 2 has one textbox.

On Button 1 Click event I am writing "My Text" in my Form 2 TextBox and on button 2 I am showing Form 2.

What is happening is when I close my Form 2 using close [X] button and reopen it value in my Form 2 Textbox Disappears.

Please Help how can I resolve this

Form 1 Code:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Form2.Text1.Text = "Parth"
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
   Form2.Show
End Sub
```

Form 2 Code:

```
Private Sub Form_QueryUnload(Cancel As Integer, UnloadMode As Integer)
   Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: It isn't sufficient to simply hide your form in the query unload event - the unload still occurs. You need to also set the Cancel argument to a non-zero value in order to cancel the form unload.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445536(v=vs.60).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form_QueryUnload(Cancel As Integer, UnloadMode As Integer)
   'Cancel=true
   Cancel=UnloadMode<>vbFormCode
   Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: System events can't be ignored safely.

Comment: @Bob77, what are you saying ...?

Comment: I'm saying your code fails if things like Windows shutdown occur, Task Manager termination was requested, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Form1:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Form2.Text1.Text = "Parth"
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Form2.Show vbModal, Me 'Since we are the owner, Form2 unloads when we do.
End Sub
```

If Form1 was not made the owner you'd need to explicitly unload Form2 within Form1's Unload event handler to avoid hanging the program.

You need to be careful not to test for the wrong UnloadMode value.

Form2:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_QueryUnload(Cancel As Integer, UnloadMode As Integer)
    If UnloadMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
       Cancel = True
       Hide
    End If
End Sub
```